# cloning a live drupal website (db) to a local / working mamp version

Tags: database

I have a drupal multi-site project, that I've inherited. I am stuck on the process of trying to clone or import the database from a live server to the local enviroment. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might be able to do this?

It would have to be done via the command line, as the I don't have access to `phpmyadmin` from the live server. I know this can be done, with a series of commands and scripts -- I'm just not sure how...

Answer (score 0):

I use this command to dump my databases which are hosted on Ubuntu:

mysqldump -uusername -p --databases db_name | gzip -f > db_name.sql.gz